# how to apply my group node to multiple different materials?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I have made a group node for one material. Now i want to use this group node for multiple different materials. Is there a shorter way than just copying it manually in every material which is very tidy...?

Comment: Maybe scripting. Have you tried that? And what you mean by "apply" a group node?

Comment: i mean just "use" -> add it before the output. Well...äh...scripting....i still have to learn that, all i did until now was using command line ...and calling some mini python scripts.... for sure, this i could not do at the moment unfortunately :(

Comment: As far as i understood, you made a node group and you want it to go to other materials as well? Well, if it is a node group then in the shader editor Shift + A -> Group -> That group you made. And remember that you can still just use Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V for nodes as well.

Comment: i know i can do ctrl + c and ctrl + v - > but then i have to do this for every material i have, right? so, click on material, then tap ctrl + v, then move the node to the right place, and this for all 100 materials (ok, a bit less), but i hoped for something like ctrl-L functionality ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this while trying to do the same. At some version of Blender the functionality was added so groups from other materials (or the currently edited on) appear at the bottom of the **Add->Group** options **Make Group** and **Ungroup**

Comment: Thx for your answer, but unfortunately this doesn't help with my question.

Comment: OK @Chris I probably misunderstood your question. It does seem  tidier to me to just `Shift-A` on the new material where you want to reuse a node group then select the group from the menu. I think you will always need to connect the node group to the other nodes in the material as you require - I can't see that being done automatically for you.